# Kendo ui grid , merged filtering

Tags: asp.net, grid, kendo-ui

I am using `Kendo ui Grid` (from kendo web) with remote binding (asp.net).

I want to have filtering on some columns on server side, others client side.

i.e., I have columns `order_id`, `user_name`, amount`.

If a user applies filters on `order_id` or `user_name` - filtering was done on server side
and if user applies filter on `amount` - filtering was done on client side.

Is there a way to handle this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't supported. If you enable server filtering it applies for all fields unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that.
I think,I disable the server side filtering and make my own filter row. filtering on the client side I can do via grid.filter method, and on the server side using datasource.query ...